# Error response while connecting to Alibaba Cloud EDAS using python SDK

Tags: python, alibaba-cloud

Trying to access EDAS application configured in Alibaba Cloud using SDK. Below code is returning error code 401 ("Invalid User"). I have checked EDAS setup and it's only setup for my own primary account.
Appreciate if anyone can share some guidance on this.

------Code----------

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import sys from aliyunsdkcore.client
import AcsClient from aliyunsdkedas.request.v20170801
import QueryApplicationStatusRequest
import uuid from aliyunsdkcore.profile
import region_provider from aliyunsdkcore.http
import method_type as MT from aliyunsdkcore.http
import format_type as FT

try:
  reload(sys)
  sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
except NameError:
  pass except Exception as err:
    raise err

REGION = "ap-southeast-1"
PRODUCT_NAME = "Edas"
ENDPOINT = "edas.ap-southeast-1.aliyuncs.com"
ACCESS_KEY_ID = "Primary account key ID"
ACCESS_KEY_SECRET = "Primary account security key"
region_provider.add_endpoint(PRODUCT_NAME, REGION, ENDPOINT)
acs_client = AcsClient(ACCESS_KEY_ID, ACCESS_KEY_SECRET, REGION)

def query_application():
  qappreq = QueryApplicationStatusRequest.QueryApplicationStatusRequest()
  qappreq.set_AppId('457290d6-9426-49c8-835c-4133f6a4d268')
  qappresponse = acs_client.do_action_with_exception(qappreq)
  return qappresponse

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(query_application())
```

While running the above code, I am getting this output,

```
{"Code":401}
```

Comment: Your code is displaying all on one line, please fix the formatting of it.

Comment: Fix formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Error response 401 means that access is unauthorized so seems to be a problem none other than your access to the application server. According to the EDAS documentation:

> The sub-account that corresponds to the Access Key ID used by the
>   request does not have the permission to call the API. To fix it, use
>   the primary account to authorize the sub-account.

Are you sure you have authorized your sub-account using your primary account in this case?

A primary account can define different operation permissions for its sub-accounts by creating different roles.

1. In the EDAS console, select Roles in the left-side navigation pane.
2. Click Create Role in the upper-right corner.
3. Enter a role name, select the permissions from the left-side field
   and add to the right, and click OK.

There's not much to the error message, it's simply indicating that you do not have authorization, so check the accounts and the roles in your EDAS console and double-check the values.

Answer (score 0):

The Error Code `401` clearly means that you are not authorized to call the API.

If you are using the sub-account to call the API then the Access Key ID used by the request does not have the permission to call the API.

> To fix it, use the primary account to authorize the sub-account. or use the primary account access key to access the EDAS (Which is not best practice).